# Run jasmine specs via phantom, got "Can't find variable: describe"

Tags: node.js, jasmine, phantomjs

I met same problem when run it on a centOS5 linux server as CI job, with phantomJS 1.7 (I compiled it by myself)

```
Running "jasmine" task 
Testing jasmine specs via phantom 
...  
[D] ["phantomjs","onResourceReceived","GET
http://127.0.0.1:8888/test/spec/CommonTest.js"]
[D] ["phantomjs","onError","ReferenceError: Can't find variable: describe",        [{"file":"http://127.0.0.1:8888/test/spec/CommonTest.js","line":31,"function":""}]]     
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: describe 
...
```

the specs run successfully on other machine such as WinXP etc.

Answer (score 0):

At last, it’s caused by that: I created a symbolic link for “node_modules” to re-use common module, but it preventgrunt-jasmine-runner to fetch sth. (not sure yet). To resolve it, need to copy the “node_modules” files directly under project folder.